# Using $objectToArray to compress the data in one document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have multiple documents of order logs and I am trying to compress them into one document using $objectToArray. Below is the collection and the output I'm trying to figure out. I also include my query but it does not compress the data.

```
{
    "ordernumber": 21001,
    "ordername":"testorder1", 
    "status" : "Ordered",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-06-30T17:02:17.165Z")

},

{
    "ordernumber": 21001,
    "ordername":"testorder1", 
    "status" : "Order Received",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-01T03:57:47.533Z")

},

{
    "ordernumber": 21001,
    "ordername":"testorder1", 
    "status" : "Delivered",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-08-17T23:53:24.878Z")

},
{
    "ordernumber": 21002,
    "ordername":"testorder2", 
    "status" : "Ordered",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-17T23:53:24.878Z")

},
{
    "ordernumber": 21002,
    "ordername":"testorder2", 
    "status" : "Order Received",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-19T04:07:47.686Z")

},
{
    "ordernumber": 21002,
    "ordername":"testorder2", 
    "status" : "Order Cancelled",
    "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-20T15:42:23.123Z")

},
```

Each ordernumber should consist all the logs in one document
OUTPUT:

```
 {
    "ordernumber": 21001,
    "ordername":"testorder1", 
    "orderlogs": [
        {
            "status" : "Ordered",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-06-30T17:02:17.165Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Order Received",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-01T03:57:47.533Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Delivered",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-08-17T23:53:24.878Z")
        }

    ]
},
{
    "ordernumber": 21002,
    "ordername":"testorder2", 
    "orderlogs": [
        {
            "status" : "Ordered",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-17T23:53:24.878Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Order Received",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-19T04:07:47.686Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "Order Cancelled",
            "modifiedat" : ISODate("2021-07-20T15:42:23.123Z")
        }

    ]
},
```

I have a query created but it only return one array per document.(still in multiple document)

```
 {
    $project: {
    ordernumber: "$ordernumber",
     ordername:"$ordername",
    orderlogs: 
        {$objectToArray: {
        status:"$status",
        modifiedat: "$modifiedat"
                        } 
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think objectToArray will be useful in this.  Try grouping by order number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) - Add current document with [`$$ROOT`](http://nicholasjohnson.com/mongo/course/exercises/aggregation-group/)  into new field, `orderlog`.
2. `$project` - Not to display `_id`, `ordernumber`, `ordername` for `orderlog`
3. `$group` - Group by `ordernumber` and `ordername`
4. `$project` - Display `ordernumber`, `ordername`, `orderlog` fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orderlog": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "orderlog": {
        "_id": 0,
        "ordernumber": 0,
        "ordername": 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        ordernumber: "$ordernumber",
        ordername: "$ordername"
      },
      orderlogs: {
        $push: "$orderlog"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      ordernumber: "$_id.ordernumber",
      ordername: "$_id.ordername",
      orderlogs: "$orderlogs"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Me2i4t9X1BH)

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed explanation. this worked well!